# How to sum $\sum_{r=1}^n q^{(r-1)k}$?

Tags: summation

I need to find $$\sum_{r=1}^n q^{(r-1)k}$$ but I'm unsure on how to do this. Any help? I believe it may be something to do with a geometric progression but I'm not sure what to do with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\sum_{r=1}^n q^{(r-1)k} = q^{-k}\sum_{r=1}^n (q^{   k})^r.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:$$\large \sum_{r=1}^n q^{(r-1)k}=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \left(q^k\right)^r$$

Now use that $$\large\sum_{r = 0}^{n_1} (a)^r = \frac{1-a^n}{1-a}$$
by substituting $a=q^k,n_1=n-1$

But if $a=q^k=1$, then we have an indeterminate answer. Can you find out what it equals when $q^k=1$?

Comment: No sorry, and I don't get your notation what does the n mean here?

Comment: @RyanK $$\sum_{n\ge 1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty$$

Comment: But Ryan's sum was finite, no need to complicate it with that.

Comment: Okay thanks, I don't understand though as my sum is from 1 to n so how can I use the formula for a sum from 0 to n?

Comment: @RyanK I changed the index of r by one, so it would be $\sum_{r=0} q^{k^r}$

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed a geometric progression, use $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$.

Answer (score 0):

If $q^k = 1$, the sum equals $n$. If $q^k \neq 1$, it's a geometric sum with common ratio $q^k$ and initial term $1$, so  the sum is equal  to $$\frac{(q^k)^n - 1}{q^k - 1} = \frac{q^{nk} - 1}{q^k - 1}$$